# Android / Cordova performance comparison

Tags: android, performance, cordova

I'm trying to compare *"Cross platform mobile application development tools"* vs *"Android Native development"* from a performance perspective. In order to do that I developed an application which makes a calculation of a serie. Below I transcript Android and Phonegap code.

**Android**

```
double serie;
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
serie = 0;
for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
    for (int k = 1; k <= 100000; k++) {
        serie = serie + Math.log(k) / Math.log(2) + (3 * k / (2 * j)) + Math.sqrt(k) + Math.pow(k, j - 1);
    }
}
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;
```

**Phonegap**

```
var start = new Date().getTime();  
var serie = 0;
for ( var j=1; j <= 5; j++ ){
    for ( var k=1; k <= 100000; k++ ){
         serie = serie + ( Math.log(k)/Math.LN2 ) + (3*k/2*j) + Math.sqrt(k) + Math.pow(k, j-1);
    }
}

var end = new Date().getTime();
var duration = end - start;
```

Each timing was taken thirty times and the results were averaged.

**Results**

Android average time = 532.93ms
Phonegap average time = 230.33ms

The results are far from what I expected. I don't understand why Android performance is worse than Phonegap's. Both applications are run as release versions.

The device is a *Moto G2 (Android 4.4)*

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this performance comparison makes any sense. You simply perform some computation in Java and then in JavaScript. After that, you measure computation time. It doesn't prove anything.

The only conclusion you could have is the fact that JavaScript performed this particular computation faster than Java for some reason. Maybe JavaScript optimized something under the hood. As it's dynamically typed language, you should check if Java and JavaScript code returned the same result, because I'm not sure about that. Moreover, you are measuring time in a different ways in two tests. Maybe `System.currentTimeMillis();` simply takes more time than `new Date().getTime();` ?

In real life, you put non-deterministic and long operations to a separate thread different than UI thread. When operation is done, you can pass the result to the UI thread. Bad project structure and bad programming practices can slow down your application. With cross-platform tools like Phonegap, you have no control over Java code and you have very limited access to low level optimization techniques and multi-threading. You also have no direct access to Android SDK.

If you really want to analyze performance, you should prepare more realistic instrumentation test. For example, create application (in two versions: Android & Phone Gap), which reads some data from a file and images from disk and then displays it on the list and with instrumentation test, you can scroll the list down to the bottom. Afterwards, you can measure time of whole instrumentation test in both cases. Having something like that, you can make some assumptions.

Comment: Both apps return the same result. @piotr.wittchen